# How to find data current slide using jquery

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have number pagination 1,2,3,4...

```
<ul id="data-total" class="slice-pagination" data-current="4" data-total="22">
   <li class="page" data-page="1">1.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="2">2.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="3">3.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="4">4.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

If I click pagination 1, The first slider will show.

And the ***data-page*** value show in ***data-current***.

Now I want to get the ***data-current*** value

MY jquery code

```js
$("#data-total").on("click",".page", function(){
  $(this).data('current'); 
  var sliceIdB = $(this).val();
  console.log(sliceIdB);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data-total" class="slice-pagination" data-current="4" data-total="22">
   <li class="page" data-page="1">1.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="2">2.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="3">3.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="4">4.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('#data-total').data('current ')`

Comment: so what you tried so far?And your question is bit unclear that whay you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that on click of `li`, you want to:-

1.get the `data-page` value of the current clicked `li`

2.Replace `ul` `data-current` attribute older value with this new value.

3.print this value.

SoYou change code a bit

```js
$("#data-total").on("click",".page", function(){
  var sliceIdB = $(this).data('page');
  $('#data-total').data('current',sliceIdB);
  console.log(sliceIdB);
  console.log($('#data-total').data('current'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="data-total" class="slice-pagination" data-current="4" data-total="22">
   <li class="page" data-page="1">1.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="2">2.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="3">3.jpg</li>
   <li class="page" data-page="4">4.jpg</li>
</ul>
```